# React DND drop event on `useDrop` not triggering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-dnd

I'm trying to implement `react-dnd` with `HTML5Backend` in my project, first I tried to implement it manually and then used exact same code from the `react-dnd` example [link](https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/examples/dustbin/single-target). but `drop` event is not triggering, even `hover` is triggering and consoled `monitor.canDrop()` it returned `true`. Anyone has any idea what causing the issue,

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

My project was running on a sharepoint environment, the issue was related to its parent container preventing the drop event, I couldn't solve the issue on the development environment, but no issue on production.